# Basic question regarding construction of likelihood function from a Cox PH model

Tags: density-function, cox-model, likelihood

I have a simple question (which I sense may have a complicated answer) regarding the fundamental logic concerning how the likelihood function from a Cox PH model is derived.

Assuming the $i^{th}$ person has a random time to event $T_{i}$ with density function $f_{i}(t|X_{i})$ then the Cox PH model for the hazard rate of an event is assumed to be $h_{i}(t|X_{i})=h_{0}(t)\exp(X_{i}\beta)$ so that the survival function $S_{i}(t|X_{i}):=P\{T_{i}>t\}$ is given by $S_{i}(t|X_{i})=\exp(-\int_{0}^{t}h_{i}(t|X_{i})du)$, and $f_{i}(t|X_{i})=h_{i}(t|X_{i})S_{i}(t|X_{i})$.

Let $C_{i}$ denote the random censoring time, and let $D_{i}=1$ denote that the subject was not censored and $D_{i}=0$ that the subject was censored. Finally let $\tilde{T_{i}}$ denote the observed event time, which might be $T_{i}$ or the observed value of $C_{i}$ (denote this by $\tilde{C_{i}}$).

If $D_{i}=1$ then $T_{i}=\tilde{T_{i}}$ and so the subject contributes $f_{i}(\tilde{T_{i}}|X_{i})$ to the likelihood function - this to me is clear. However if $D_{i}=0$ then $T_{i}=\tilde{C_{i}}$ and in this case the subject apparently contributes $S_{i}(\tilde{C_{i}}|X_{i})=P\{T_{i}>\tilde{C_{i}}\}$ to the likelihood function - whilst this feels intuitively correct, I don't understand this mathematically since $S_{i}(\tilde{C_{i}}|X_{i})$  is a probability and not a density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that, ultimately, the likelihood is the product of probabilities...not densities.  The use of densities relies on the notion that the density can proxy for for the probability if we consider the finite region around the value.

So $S[C_i|X_i]=P[T_i>C_i]$ is closer in spirit to a likelihood term than $f_i(T_i|X_i)$ is.

See the [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Likelihoods_for_continuous_distributions)

Comment: Thank-you very much @StatNoodle - I didn't realise that the definition of the likelihood function (that says $L(\theta|X)\equiv cL(\theta|X)$) permits densities to be used instead of probabilities