# a question about a proof here involving real analysis or measure theory

Tags: stochastic-processes, measure-theory

i have a question about a proof here that I was reading:
[image]

Basically what I don't understand is the last sentence of the proof where it says:

$Pr{\{t<S_{n+1} \leq t + \delta\}} = f_{S_{n+1}}(t)(\delta + o(\delta))$ is simply a consequence of the fact that ... has a continuous ... in the interval [t, t+$\delta$].

Could someone explains how to get from the left to the right of the equality by using the property of "continuous function" here?

Sorry I think it has to do with real-analysis, or measure theory? by my background is week, so I don't get how to use the "continuous function" property to arrive at what the author wrote here.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Very good question, I ran into this question for a different reason when I posted this question about the likelihood function for a Cox PH model;

[Basic question regarding construction of likelihood function from a Cox PH model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189213/basic-question-regarding-construction-of-likelihood-function-from-a-cox-ph-model)

The answer was related to the point you raise here about probabilities in arbitrarily small "elements" about a point (arbitrarily small intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ say) are equal to the density value at the point. This result comes from the fundamental relationship between $F(x)$ the distribution and $f(x)$ the density, that is $d/dxF(x)=f(x)$.

$F(x)$ here means the distribution function where $F(x)=\mu(-\infty,x]=P[X\leq x]$ and where $\mu$ is the probability law or distribution of $X$ satisfying the relationship

$$P[X\in A]=\mu(A)=\int_{A}f(x)dx$$

Thus putting $A=(-\infty,x]$ we get

$$\frac{d}{dx}P[X\in A]=\frac{d}{dx}P[X\leq x]
=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_{(-\infty,x]}f(x)dx\right]=f(x)$$

The underlying mathematics behind the $d/dx F(x)=f(x)$ is the fundamental theorem of calculus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

The link here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Likelihoods_for_continuous_distributions

given by the answer to my question shows the impact all this has on the likelihood function (i.e. maximising the likelihood for fixed small element about a point is the same as maximising the likelihood defined in terms of the density of that point).

In terms of your result shown from the paper, the link I gave shows the following limit applies;

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{(x,x+\epsilon]}f(x)dx=f(x)$$

and stems from this fundamental theorem of calculus, thus it is tempting (but not mathematically rigourous without the $o$ notation) to say

$$\int_{(x,x+\epsilon]}f(x)dx\approx\epsilon f(x)$$

and so from the previous relationship between $F$ and $f$

$$\int_{(x,x+\epsilon]}f(x)dx=\mu\left\{(x,x+\epsilon]\right\}=P[X\in(x,x+\epsilon]]\approx\epsilon f(x)$$

Thus without the formalitites of the $o$ notation I think of this result as saying the probability of $X$ being in a arbitrarily small element $(x,x+\epsilon]$ is the area of the arbitrarily narrow "rectangle" given by height=$f(x)$ multiplied by length $\epsilon$

#### EDIT: $o$-notation

For any function $g(x)$ with derivative $g'$ at $x_{0}$ by definition we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{g(x_{0}+\delta)-g(\delta)}{\delta}\underset{\delta\rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} g'(x_{0})
\end{align*}

Which implies

\begin{align*}
\frac{g(x_{0}+\delta)-g(\delta)-\delta g'(x_{0})}{\delta}\underset{\delta\rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{align*}

Let the notation $o(\delta)$ be a function of $\delta$ such that $o(\delta)/\delta\longrightarrow 0$ as $\delta\longrightarrow 0$. For example $C\delta^{2}=o(\delta)$ for any constant $C$ will do since $(C\delta^{2})/\delta=C\delta\longrightarrow 0$ as $\delta\longrightarrow 0$. Similarly $[C o(\delta)]/\delta=C[o(\delta)/\delta]\longrightarrow 0$ by definition of $o(\delta)$ so that $C o(\delta)$ is $o(\delta)$. But $C\delta$ is not $o(\delta)$ since $(C\delta)/\delta=C$ which is constant. The idea is that many functions could be $o(\delta)$ but the lack of uniqueness does not matter - only the limiting behaviour matters. With this in mind from above

\begin{align*}
\frac{g(x_{0}+\delta)-g(\delta)-\delta g'(x_{0})}{\delta}=o(\delta)=C o(\delta)
\end{align*}

which gives

\begin{align*}
g(x_{0}+\delta)-g(\delta)=\delta[ g'(x_{0})+ Co(\delta)]
\end{align*}

Replacing $g$ with $F$, $f'$ with $F'=f$, $x_{0}$ with $t_{0}$ and choosing $C=f(t_{0})$ we get

\begin{align*}
F(t_{0}+\delta)-F(\delta)&=\delta[ f(t_{0})+ f(t_{0})o(\delta)]\\
&=\delta f(t_{0})+\delta f(t_{0})o(\delta)\\
&=f(t_{0})[\delta+\delta o(\delta)]
\end{align*}

But $[\delta o(\delta)]/\delta=o(\delta)$ so that $\delta o(\delta)$ is itself $o(\delta)$. Thus

\begin{align*}
F(t_{0}+\delta)-F(\delta)&=f(t_{0})[\delta+ o(\delta)]
\end{align*}

Thus

\begin{align*}
Pr\{X\in (t_{0},t_{0}+\delta]\}=f(t_{0})[\delta+ o(\delta)]
\end{align*}

Comment: This answer might be salvageable if it is completely re-written but as it stands it is mostly wrong. The distribution is the derivative of the density? Really? Probabilities of small intervals are _equal_ to the value of the density? Really?

Comment: @DilipSarwate you are right to mark me down for that answer; I was wrong to say $F(x)=d/dxf(x)$ - I meant to say $d/dxF(x)=f(x)$. But even then my notation was too vague, in particular not differentiating between distribution functions and distributions. I have edited the answer accordingly, hopefully this is close to the answer the OP needs

Comment: Hello dandar, but could you specifically address the small o notation and explain the notations and the proof in more details as stated in the proof. Because I see you are using another example. But could you use the notation in the proof in my question? Thank you. Or could someone help.

Comment: Hi @john_w I hope this helps?

Comment: It seems your explanation under edit is reasonable, but since I don't have deep enough background to know if it is 100% correct, could someone confirm the answer. Because someone give a down vote, it makes me not confidence of the answer under edit. Could someone with more expertise confirm if the answer is correct? Also what is the reason of down vote?

Comment: Hello dandar, maybe could you explain your o notation again with ONLY the property that the $S_n$ has a continuous probability function? Because this is exactly the property and probably the only property that author uses which he states in the last line of his proof. But you seems to be using some other properties which involves derivative? Could you use only the property of continuous because this is what the author uses.